# How to remove app from admob blacklist?

Tags: ios, admob, touch, banner

My Application is not showing banners, and a person from admob contacted me saying, seems it is blacklisted by Admob because the banner was too close too the game area, I have removed the banner from that page of the app, and made it not too close on other touchable areas, how can I remove it from that black list now that the app is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Once you update your app submit an appeal to admob team - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6195033?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

If Admob accepts your request your ads will be displayed again. ( Email from Admob team who wrote to you should list down next steps and links in detail )